# Problems balancing and inserting an AVL-tree

Tags: c, avl-tree

I'm writing a AVL tree code and the programm, which correct my code say always, that my balance and indert_value functions aren't gut and I can't find my mistake. Can someone please help me to find the mistake?

My code is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>  // Ein- / Ausgabe
#include <math.h>   // Für die Berechnungen der Ausgabe
#include "avl.h"


AVLNode* node_suchen(AVLTree *avlt, int value)
{
    AVLNode *t = avlt->root;
    while (t != NULL) {
        if (value == t->value) {
            return t;
        } else if (value < t->value) {
            t = t->left;
        } else {
            t = t->right;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

int heightcheck(AVLNode *node)
{
    if (node == NULL) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return node->height;
    }
}

void AVL_in_order_walk_node(AVLNode *node)
{
    if (node->left != NULL) {
        AVL_in_order_walk_node(node->left);
    }
    printf("%d ", node->value);
    if (node->right != NULL) {
        AVL_in_order_walk_node(node->right);
    }
}

void AVL_in_order_walk(AVLTree *avlt)
{
    if (avlt != NULL && avlt->root != NULL) {
        AVL_in_order_walk_node(avlt->root);
    }
}

void AVL_rotate_left(AVLTree *avlt, AVLNode *x)
{
    AVLNode *y = x->right;
    x->right = y->left;

    if (y->left != NULL) {
        y->left->parent = x;
    }
    y->parent = x->parent;
    if (x->parent == NULL) {
        avlt->root = y;
    } else if (x == x->parent->left) {
        x->parent->left = y;
    } else {
        x->parent->right = y;
    }
    y->left = x;
    x->parent = y;
    if (x->left == NULL && x->right == NULL) {
        x->height = 1;
    } else {
        int Lefth, Righth;
        Lefth = heightcheck(x->left);
        Righth = heightcheck(x->right);
        if (Lefth > Righth) {
            x->height = Lefth + 1;
        } else {
            x->height = Righth + 1;
        }
    }
    if (y->left == NULL && y->right == NULL) {
        y->height = 1;
    } else {
        int Lefth, Righth;
        Lefth = heightcheck(y->left);
        Righth = heightcheck(y->right);
        if (Lefth > Righth) {
            y->height = Lefth + 1;
        } else {
            y->height = Righth + 1;
        }
    }
}

void AVL_rotate_right(AVLTree *avlt, AVLNode *y)
{
    AVLNode *x = y->left;
    y->left = x->right;

    if (x->right != NULL) {
        x->right->parent = y;
    }
    x->parent = y->parent;
    if (y->parent == NULL) {
        avlt->root = x;
    } else if (y == y->parent->right) {
        y->parent->right = x;
    } else {
        y->parent->left = x;
    }
    x->right = y;
    y->parent = x;
    if (y->left == NULL && y->right == NULL) {
        y->height = 1;
    } else {
        int Lefth, Righth;
        Lefth = heightcheck(y->left);
        Righth = heightcheck(y->right);
        if (Lefth > Righth) {
            y->height = Lefth + 1;
        } else {
            y->height = Righth + 1;
        }
    }
    if (x->left == NULL && x->right == NULL) {
        x->height = 1;
    } else {
        int Lefth, Righth;
        Lefth = heightcheck(x->left);
        Righth = heightcheck(x->right);
        if (Lefth > Righth) {
            x->height = Lefth + 1;
        } else {
            x->height = Righth + 1;
        }
    }
}


void AVL_balance(AVLTree *avlt, AVLNode *node)
{
    if (node == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    int L, R;
    L = heightcheck(node->left);
    R = heightcheck(node->right);
    if (L > R + 1) {
        int LL, LR;
        LL = heightcheck(node->left->left);
        LR = heightcheck(node->left->right);
        if (LL < LR) {
            AVL_rotate_left(avlt, node->left);
        }
        AVL_rotate_right(avlt, node);
    } else if (R > L + 1) {
        int RR, RL;
        RR = heightcheck(node->right->right);
        RL = heightcheck(node->right->left);
        if (RR < RL) {
            AVL_rotate_right(avlt, node->right);
        }
        AVL_rotate_left(avlt, node);
    }
}

void AVL_insert_value(AVLTree *avlt, int value)
{
    AVLNode *check = node_suchen(avlt, value);
    if (check != NULL) {
        printf("Der Wert ist bereits vorhanden!\n");
        return;
    }
    AVLNode *Neunode = (AVLNode *)malloc(sizeof(AVLNode));
    Neunode->left = NULL;
    Neunode->right = NULL;
    Neunode->parent = NULL;
    Neunode->value = value;
    Neunode->height = 1;

    if (avlt->root == NULL) {
        avlt->root = Neunode;
        avlt->numberOfNodes = avlt->numberOfNodes + 1;
    } else {
        AVLNode *current = avlt->root;
        AVLNode *prev;
        while (current != NULL) {
            prev = current;
            if (current->value < value) {
                current = current->right;
            } else {
                current = current->left;
            }
        }
        if (prev->value < value) {
            prev->right = Neunode;
            Neunode->parent = prev;
            avlt->numberOfNodes = avlt->numberOfNodes + 1;
        } else {
            prev->left = Neunode;
            Neunode->parent = prev;
            avlt->numberOfNodes = avlt->numberOfNodes + 1;
        }
    }
//balance after node inserted
    AVLNode *t = Neunode;
    while (t != NULL) {
        AVL_balance(avlt, t);
        if (t->parent != NULL) {
            if (t->parent->left == NULL && t->parent->right == NULL) {
                t->parent->height = 1;
            } else {
                int Lefth, Righth;
                Lefth = heightcheck(t->parent->left);
                Righth = heightcheck(t->parent->right);
                if (Lefth > Righth) {
                    t->parent->height = Lefth + 1;
                } else {
                    t->parent->height = Righth + 1;
                }
            }
        }
        t = t->parent;
    }
}

void AVL_remove_all_node(AVLNode *node)
{
    if (node->left != NULL) {
        AVL_remove_all_node(node->left);
    }
    if (node->right != NULL) {
        AVL_remove_all_node(node->right);
    }
    free(node);
}

void AVL_remove_all_elements(AVLTree *avlt)
{
    if (avlt != NULL) {
        AVL_remove_all_node(avlt->root);
    } else {
        free(avlt);
    }
}
```

there are also two libraries

the first one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "avl.h"

int main(int argc, char **args)
{
    if (argc < 1 || argc > 2) {
        printf("Nutzung: %s [Dateiname]\n", args[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *input = NULL;
    if (argc == 1) {
        input = stdin;
    } else {
        input = fopen(args[1], "r");
        if (input == NULL) {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    // erzeuge leeren Suchbaum
    AVLTree avlt;
    avlt.root = NULL;
    avlt.numberOfNodes = 0;

    // führe operationen auf dem Baum aus
    execute_operations(&avlt, input);

    // gib den Speicher frei
    AVL_remove_all_elements(&avlt);

    if (argc == 2) {
        fclose(input);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and the other one:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>      //Ein- / Ausgabe
#include <assert.h>     //Immer auf der richtigen Seite!
#include <math.h>       //Für die Berechnungen der Ausgabe
#include <string.h>
#include "avl.h"

int left(int i)
{
    return 2 * i + 1;
}

int right(int i)
{
    return 2 * i + 2;
}

// Kopiere Knoten rekursiv in ein Array
void fill_array(AVLNode *node, AVLNode **node_array, int current_position)
{
    node_array[current_position] = node;
    if (node->left != NULL) {
        fill_array(node->left, node_array, left(current_position));
    }
    if (node->right != NULL) {
        fill_array(node->right, node_array, right(current_position));
    }

}


int find_max_value(AVLNode *node)
{
    while (node->right != NULL) {
        node = node->right;
    }
    return node->value;
}


char* draw_AVL_tree(AVLTree *avlt)
{
    assert(avlt != NULL);

    if (avlt->root == NULL) {
        return (strdup("Baum ist leer!"));
    }

    // Different height measure for drawing tree (single node has height of 1)
    int height = avlt->root->height + 1;

    // maximale Anzahl an Blättern ist 2^height
    int max_leaves = (1 << height);

    // berechne die maximal benötigte Breite der Knoten
    int entry_width = (int)(ceil(log10(abs(find_max_value(avlt->root)))));
    if (entry_width % 2 == 0) {
        entry_width++;
    }

    // ein paar weitere Konstanten
    int entry_spacing = 1;
    int line_width = max_leaves * entry_width + (max_leaves - 1) * entry_spacing;
    int max_node_count = max_leaves * 2;

    // lege ein 2d-Array von Chars für die Ausgabe an
    char **string_buffer = malloc(sizeof(char *) * ((height)*2));
    for (int y = 0; y <= (height - 1) * 2 + 1; ++y) {
        string_buffer[y] = malloc(sizeof(char) * line_width + 2);
        for (int x = 0; x < line_width; ++x) {
            string_buffer[y][x] = ' ';
        }
        string_buffer[y][line_width] = '\n';
        string_buffer[y][line_width + 1] = '\0';
    }

    // speichere alle Knoten des Graphs in einem Array
    AVLNode **node_array = malloc(max_node_count * sizeof(AVLNode *));
    for (int i = 0; i < max_node_count; ++i) {
        node_array[i] = NULL;
    }
    fill_array(avlt->root, node_array, 0);


    // berechne (mittels dynamischer Programmierung) die Positionen
    // jedes einzelnen Knoten
    int *position_pointer = malloc(max_node_count * sizeof(int));
    for (int level = height; level >= 0; level--) {

        int index_of_first_node_in_level = ((1 << level) - 1);
        if (level == height) {
            //der unterste, linkeste Knoten wird bündig links ausgegeben
            position_pointer[index_of_first_node_in_level] = 0;

            // alle anderen Knoten sind (entry_spacing+entry_width) weit entfernt
            for (int i = 1; i < (1 << level); ++i) {
                position_pointer[index_of_first_node_in_level + i] = position_pointer[index_of_first_node_in_level + i - 1] + entry_spacing + entry_width;
            }
        } else {
            // für Knoten in höheren Schichten nehmen wir das arithmetische Mittel der Kinderpositionen
            for (int i = 0; i < (1 << level); ++i) {
                position_pointer[index_of_first_node_in_level + i] = (position_pointer[left(index_of_first_node_in_level + i)] + position_pointer[right(index_of_first_node_in_level + i)]) / 2;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int y = (height - 1) * 2; y >= 0; y -= 2) {
        int level = y / 2;
        int index_of_first_node_in_level = ((1 << level) - 1);

        // Schreibe die Knoten..
        for (int i = 0; i < (1 << level); ++i) {
            AVLNode *current_node = node_array[index_of_first_node_in_level + i];
            char *curr_pointer = string_buffer[y] + position_pointer[index_of_first_node_in_level + i];
            if (current_node != NULL) {
                // füge Leerzeichen hinzu falls notwendig..
                int trailing_spaces = (int)(floor((entry_width - (ceil(log10(abs(current_node->value))))) / 2));
                if (trailing_spaces > 0) {
                    curr_pointer += trailing_spaces;
                }
                int len = sprintf(curr_pointer, "%d", current_node->value);
                curr_pointer[len] = ' ';
            }
        }
        if (y < (height - 1) * 2) {
            // Schreibe die Kanten
            for (int i = 0; i < (1 << level); ++i) {
                int position = index_of_first_node_in_level + i;
                if (node_array[left(position)] != NULL) {
                    char *curr_pointer = string_buffer[y + 1];
                    for (int k = position_pointer[left(position)] + entry_width / 2; k <= position_pointer[position] + entry_width / 2 - 1; ++k) {
                        curr_pointer[k] = '-';
                    }
                    curr_pointer[position_pointer[left(position)] + entry_width / 2] = '/';
                    curr_pointer[position_pointer[position] + entry_width / 2] = '|';
                }
                if (node_array[right(position)] != NULL) {
                    char *curr_pointer = string_buffer[y + 1];
                    for (int k = position_pointer[right(position)] + entry_width / 2; k >= position_pointer[position] + entry_width / 2 + 1; --k) {
                        curr_pointer[k] = '-';
                    }
                    curr_pointer[position_pointer[right(position)] + entry_width / 2] = '\\';
                    curr_pointer[position_pointer[position] + entry_width / 2] = '|';
                }
            }
        }

    }

    // länge für rückgabestring bestimmen
    size_t ostrlen = 1;
    for (int y = 0; y <= (height)*2 - 1; ++y) {
        ostrlen += strlen(string_buffer[y]);
    }
    char *ostr = calloc(ostrlen, sizeof(char));
    char *ostrp = ostr;

    // baut den String und gibt allen Speicher wieder frei
    for (int y = 0; y <= (height)*2 - 1; ++y) {
        ostrp = stpncpy(ostrp, string_buffer[y], ostrlen - (ostrp - ostr));
        free(string_buffer[y]);
    }
    free(string_buffer);
    free(position_pointer);
    free(node_array);
    return (ostr);
}


void print_AVL_tree(AVLTree *avlt)
{
    char *tr = draw_AVL_tree(avlt);
    printf("%s\n", tr);
    free(tr);
}
void execute_operations(AVLTree *avlt, FILE *input)
{
    char buffer[255];
    int abort = 0;
    while (!abort && (fgets(buffer, 255, input) != NULL)) {
        char operation;
        int value;

        int result = sscanf(buffer, "%d", &value);
        if (result != 1) {
            result = sscanf(buffer, "%c", &operation);
            if (result != 1) {
                printf("fgets/sscanf konnte die Eingabe nicht parsen...!\n");
            } else {
                if (operation == 'p') {
                    print_AVL_tree(avlt);
                } else if (operation == 'w') {
                    AVL_in_order_walk(avlt);
                } else if (operation == 'q') {
                    abort = 1;
                } else if (operation == 'c') {
                    printf("Im AVL-Baum sind %d Elemente enthalten.\n", avlt->numberOfNodes);
                } else {
                    printf("Zeichen %c wird ignoriert\n", operation);
                }
            }
        } else {
            printf("Füge %d ein...\n", value);
            AVL_insert_value(avlt, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry if it is too complicated or if I didn't explain my self.

Comment: "...which correct my code say always, that my balance and indert_value functions aren't gut...". What does that mean? You posted your code, but haven't told us what it does and how that's a problem.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: In other words, we need to see actual inputs and outputs, and an example of the expected output.